# Will partitioning a SQL table break a 3rd party app

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

We have some 3rd party apps that make heavy use of SQL server. We've optimized as much as we can with indexes, but performance is still poor.

My next thought was to try partitioning, but have no idea if this will be transparent to the app. Can I partition the data without breaking any SQL queries from the app?

Comment: It should be transparent to the app.  I mean, if the app queries the database to count the partitions and fails if there is more than one, then there is nothing you can do.  But if it is just doing normal SQL operations, then you should be fine.

Comment: In MS SQL all tables/indexes by default are partioned and have one partition. So for normal queries which don't use partitions count explicitly all will be fine. But will they be slowed down or speeded up will depends on a particular query and partition keys.

Comment: Partitioning is not a silver bullet to make everything go faster (if it was, it would be the default). The only way this could potentially speed up your application is, if **all** queries (or at least those that need to be faster) always include the column(s) of the partitioning key in the `where` clause with an `=` condition.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. New partitioning will not break your queries. It's all happening 'under the hood' and not visible to the app. To maximize the chances of speeding up of your queries make sure that your partition scheme is being used properly (Indexes->Select index->Properties->Storage->Partition Scheme).